# SSL certification exception- error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, ldap, tomcat

I am using LDAP authentication in Tomcat. But I'm getting the exception

```
 SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler 
 ["http-apr-4001"]
 java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key 
 C:/Usersuser/Documents/SSLcertificate/mycertfilepem.pem 
 (error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line)

 SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-4001]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component 
 [Connector[HTTP/1.1-4001]] 
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler 
 initialization failed
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key 
 C:/Users/user/Documents/SSLcertificate/mycertfilepem.pem 
 (error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line)
```

I have no clue what this means despite searching about it. I referred
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste but the error is a bit different from the one I'm facing. I used the command

"**openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server-domain.com:3269 > C:\Users\user\Documents\SSLcertificate\mycertfile.pem**"

to import ssl certificate from ldap server to my local. When i use this ssl certificate for ldap authentication through Java program it works. But when I use it for ldap authentication through Tomcat I'm getting the exception
        **error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line**.

The ssl certificate looks something like this

```
CONNECTED(000002B8)
    ---
    Certificate chain
     0 s:/CN=domain1.corp.regn.net
       i:/DC=net/DC=regn/DC=corp/CN=domain1
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIGfjCCBWagAwIBAgITYgAAIET2TOp0vhL5/wAAAAAgRDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
    ADBaMRMwEQYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYDbmV0MRQwEgYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYEcmVnbjEV
    ...
    YrArO/SbuQwdEFSFGUKT3/QB400arvKDyFPOerw9FgN4wc+ZUu9/CyyJg4z5gQur
    wz249UBs7lh6voouY94vdPOrH2qPWS+WhM7w8dDH6qQjrnQdH9AttWqeLCUnIx1b
    giuBuJLObfjy9pOvY/nmeosgDS3/o7E2C0/oWUNAMt79/A==
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
     1 s:/DC=net/DC=regn/DC=corp/CN=domain1
       i:/DC=net/DC=regn/CN=domain2
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIHcjCCBVqgAwIBAgITNwAAAAlMh9zQLi9kJwAAAAAACTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
    ADBDMRMwEQYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYDbmV0MRQwEgYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYEcmVnbjEW
    MBQGA1UEAxMNTkFQREEyUEtJUDAzNjAeFw0xOTAxMjMyMDU2NTJaFw0yNDAxMjMy
    ......

    hnTXXvt0puYpZcVbnO6+WwGCQ5qzXmJUXVLUUOeZUvoY4D/l+qXqQpTZSP2MpF21
    9x9VaB6kiBRfNMW5fWCz2t9pdWzbUPMKa8s5K+yXpZCQbDmfUf4=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    ---
    Server certificate
    subject=/CN=doamin.corp.regn.net
    issuer=/DC=net/DC=regn/DC=legal/CN=domain
    ---
    Acceptable client certificate CA names
    /CN=domain1.corp.regn.net
    /CN=Azure ATP Sensor
    ..
    /DC=com/DC=microsoft/CN=Certificate Authority
    /CN=NT AUTHORITY
    Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
    Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 6467 bytes and written 454 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is d23r2r2r
    Server public key is 2048 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    No ALPN negotiated
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1
        Cipher    : #####
        Session-ID: d23e232f
        Session-ID-ctx: 
        Master-Key: ####
        Key-Arg   : None
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        Start Time: 1565104395
        Timeout   : 300 (sec)
        Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    ---
```

Connector in server.xml file of tomcat is

```
   <Connector port="4001" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           clientAuth="true"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           secure="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="C:/Users/user/Documents/SSLcertificate/mycertfilepem.pem"
           keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_212/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
           keystorePass="changeit"
           />
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the contents of mycertfile.pem is exactly what you show above? The contents should only be the ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--- and ---END CERTIFICATE--- and the contents between (as is mentioned in the post you referenced).

I should add too, that the server.xml <Connector> section is used to specify what Tomcat is listening on, and the SSLCertificateFile you reference is the SSL certificate that Tomcat will be using to provide SSL (HTTPS) services.  You probably want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192981/how-do-i-set-up-tomcat-with-authentication-in-ldap